# What data structure for this operation?

Tags: data-structures, arrays

Say I have two arrays, { energy and score }, and they could have elements like this:

```
E: 1  3  4 7
S: 16 10 5 1
```

What I want is the best score with the best energy. What data structure can support inserting items in a way that I don't have have an item with less energy and less score than another item `i.e. for any i,j where i!=j => score[i] > score[j] || energy[i] > energy[j]`

When inserting, I do three steps:
1- if any item has more or equal score and energy, return;
2- if any item has less or equal score and energy, remove this item;
3- insert the required item.

Here are some examples:
1- insert e=8, s=1. The arrays become:

```
E: 1  3  4 8
S: 16 10 5 1
           ^
```

2- insert e=5, s=6. The arrays becomes:

```
E: 1  3  5 8
S: 16 10 6 1
         ^
```

3- insert e=5, s=11. The arrays becomes :

```
E: 1  5  8
S: 16 11 1
      ^    (3,10) is removed because (5,11) has more energy and more score than it.
```

What data structure can support this in (hopefully) O(logn) time?

Comment: See also http://cs.stackexchange.com/q/44670/755, https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pareto_efficiency#Use_in_engineering, https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Skyline_operator.  And welcome to CS.SE!

Comment: [Also posted on SO](http://stackoverflow.com/q/39069933/781723).
Please [do not post the same question on multiple sites](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/64068). Each community should have an honest shot at answering without anybody's time being wasted.