# Measuring the Union of Products of Intervals

Tags: complexity-theory, computational-geometry, partial-order

**Verbose Motivation for this Question**

Inspired by [this paper](http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download?doi=10.1.1.160.6270&rep=rep1&type=pdf) about how the problem of counting unlabelled subtrees that are unique up to isomorphism is #P-complete, I was thinking about the problem for the specific case of caterpillar graphs. (a caterpillar graph, $C$, will become a path graph, $P(C)$, by removing all their leaves) This lead me to an interesting subproblem, where, given an array $[l_0,l_1 \dots l_d]$ you need to compute:

$$ \sum_{i=0}^d \int \bigcup_{k=0}^{d-i} \prod_{j=k}^{k+i} [0,l_j]$$

Here, we are taking a Lebesgue unit measure of a union of $(i+1)$-dimensional intervals. (for each cartesian product, the length of 1st dimension is $[0,l_k]$, and the $m$th dimension is $[0,l_{j+m}]$) This monstrous equation arises due to the partial-order of possible sub-trees which include exactly $(i+1)$ vertices of $P(C)$. (in the actual problem, it's a little complicated, because you have to account for over-counting due to symmetry that occurs from reversing the order of your array, but for now I'll just concern myself with the cleaner subproblem)

**My actual questions**

I'm curious about computing the Lebesgue unit measure of the union of $n$ $i$-dimensional intervals which are each defined by a list of $i$ 2-tuples which are represent a cartesian product along orthogonal axes.

1. What's the complexity of measuring the union of $n$ $i$-dimensional intervals? (I found that this is [Klee's measure problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Klee%27s_measure_problem#Known_bounds), we specifically have $O(n^{d/2})$ for dimensions $d \geq 3$, and $O(nlog(n))$ for $d =1,2$)
2. Are there significant improvements in the case were intervals have some obvious partial-order? (ex: each interval is a subset of $[0, +\infty]^i$, and have a corner at $[0]^i$)
3. Similarly, are there note-worthy improvements if we restrict ourselves to intervals whose corners all belong to $\mathbb{Z}^i$?

Upon further consideration, I feel like the answer to [this question](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/44670/minimum-subset-of-dominating-2d-points/44678#44678) might be quite useful for my second question. However, I am still unclear exactly what's the best way to calculate measure once we've identified the relevant intervals, and if the $O(nlog(n))$ sorting generalizes to higher dimensions.